# Target WebKit browsers only in CSS? (2019 Edition)

Tags: css, webkit, target

Have been using the neat little

> @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {}

selector until now, and it worked flawlessly. But since a few months, FireFox is also able to process this code, as well as Microsoft Edge apparently.

So yeah, are there any working alternatives left for a CSS-only approach?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Vendor prefixed rules should work with any corresponding layout engine.

Comment: We used to be able to write CSS code that would only work on WebKit browsers (Chrome, Opera, Safari, etc.) with the CSS selector in my opening post. But this is no longer possible since Firefox and Edge are now able to understand the above mentioned vendor prefixed rule. (And many others for that matter)

Comment: @jmargolisvt: You may want to familiarize yourself with the current state of affairs surrounding the -webkit- prefix specifically. In short, people were relying too much on that prefix and unwarrantedly excluding other engines from rendering layouts that they would have been entirely capable of rendering had the appropriate other prefixes or unprefixed properties been provided. So other engines have been forced to process -webkit- features as a result of this negligence.

Comment: @roy Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Hey Corey, sorry for the late response. I kinda forgot about my stackoverflow account. I did find some potential methods of doing it, but ultimately settled for reworking my code to function in a universal manner across different engines.

Answer (score 1):

To target Firefox Quantum use:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  @supports (animation: calc(0s)) {
      /* Firefox Quantum specific styles */
  }
}
```

for Edge, use:

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
  /* Edge specific styles */
}
```

Comment: The question is asking how to target WebKit, not the other two. Unless you're suggesting to override the styles in each of these two competing browsers so the WebKit styles don't apply to them, which seems excessive and repetitive.